# Take action when the cursor position crosses a particular x value

Tags: python, python-3.x, cursor-position

Here is my situation

```
import win32api

while True:
    x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    if x < 0:
        print("2")
    else:
        print("1")
```

This constantly prints '1' or '2' depending on the x co-ordinate of the mouse being less than 0 (dual monitors, RHS is primary so < 0 means mouse is on second monitor). How can I make it only print **one instance** of the string '1' or '2' when x becomes < 0 or x becomes >= 0?

Comment: Have you tried taking the print statements out of the while loop? Basically you have an infinite loop since `while true` by itself is always true, which is why it prints many statements. If you don't want it to print more than once you just need to remove the while.

Comment: Taking the print statement out the while loop gives me no output whatsoever though I know for a fact 'x' is meeting the conditions as it works within the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the last state printed so that you can detect when a new state is entered.

```
last_state = False
while True:
    x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    state = x < 0
    if state == last_state:
        continue
    last_state = state
    if state:
        print("2")
    else:
        print("1")
```

Comment: This will print any time the cursor is moved. In the question (s)he is looking for it to print the output only when x changes from nonnegative to negative or vice versa. You would just need to change the first if statement to catch this.

Comment: Reworking. I think I had that in mind, because I initially had it in my head that `last_x` would be either 1 or 2.

Comment: Can you give an example? You are correct, this gives the same output as my initial example (constant output).